# How do I set the screen correctly on an Acer Aspire One 722 running Debian Linux

Tags: debian, radeon, x

I have an Acer Aspire One 722 which uses the Radeon HD 6290 to drive an LCD panel which a physical resolution of 1366 x 768. Over a year ago, I had Debian Linux running on in using this resolution.

Due to a disk error, I needed to reinstall Linux, and have been unable to find the correct settings to get it to use the physical resolution. it insists on using 1024 x 768, which is obviously stretched. xrandr refuses to set this size as it complains, incorrectly, that it would exceed the physical size.

I've obviously missed something. How do I get it to work correctly?

Note, it is using the correct ati + radeon drivers and I have installed firmware-linux-nonfree.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Acer/AspireOne_722 Scroll down to "Display".

Comment: @arochester - as I said, I already have firmware-linux-nonfree installed (reinstalling doesn't help) and I can't use the proprietary driver as that only works for Xorg up to version 1.10 (current is about 1.19). How do I check thatbthe ATI Radeon firmware is being loaded?